# Leakage current shielding technology principle

Tags: electrical-engineering

Kindly help me explain why ECSPD device can prevent leakage current and keep the light still working while they put it into water? Why short-circuits does not occur?
Product link: http://enerpark.biz/1-ec-2/?lang=en.
Test video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NYVCMusXqM
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what ECSPD means and provide links to datasheet or description of the system. Also explain what the photo is showing and give credit to the owner of the photo if it is not your own. (This is site policy.) Thanks.

Comment: This seems bogus. The screengrab you have posted includes a lot of technobabble. The site's FAQ's explanation of how an ELCB works is not correct. If there is equipotential between L & N or any two phases then there is no electromotive power and no energy can be drawn from the supply.

Comment: I don't think this is bogus because I already see this product in real life(It installs in my friend house). You can see test video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NYVCMusXqM

Comment: @NguyenThePhung In this context, snake oil doesn't mean that the lamp can't light up underwater. It means their product isn't really doing anything because it would work with out it. Pure water is not conductive. It's water with stuff dissolved in it that is conductive. You also don't know anything about the construction of the lamp they submerged. Notice there was no normal control lamp in the video.

Answer (score 1):

It's snake oil. Do NOT believe it. The "leakage current shielding technology" (see NOTE1) has nothing common with such things as physics, math and engineering. It's pure nonsense created by people who want money. Internet is full of trash. Some of it is made by pure humorists like many free energy videos. As said, this one is an attempt to get your money.

The shown lamp can work for ex. with +5VDC, it can be fully isolated from the mains AC, everything sunken can be watertight or the person who keeps his hands in water at the same time when the lamp gets a bath has made sure he is well isolated from anything connected to the ground. And the water pool made of glass or plastics doesn't allow any leak to ground direct from the water. I would believe only after having one in my hands and seeing with measurements it works.

Residual current circuit breaker is the way to go and in many countries no mains AC electricity distribution installations are legal without them. Read its idea from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device

**NOTE1** the device may still do something more than only exist, cost and maybe work as metallic conductor. If such functionality exists it is 100% hidden in the advertisements. In theory it could be a real help against electric shock if it lifts enough the AC output frequency or fully isolates its output from the rest of the mains AC distribution network. The former is useless with appliances which assume 50 or 60 Hz AC voltage input. The latter is useful only if it's connected to feed exactly one appliance and can handle its power demand.